# Android View setBackgroundColor not working in custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I have an Android list activity with a custom cursor adapter that retrieves items from the DB. It's supposed to set the text of the view with the retrieved item's name, and set the background as the item's set color, stored in the DB as an integer. The name is being set as expected, but the color is not changing. Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView colorName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.color_desc);
        colorName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(THREAD_DESC)));
        view.setBackgroundColor(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(THREAD_COLOR)));
    }
```

The views in the list all show the correct color name, but with a white background. I tried setting the color to preset Java colors, and the views still end up white. Changing it from view.setBackgroundColor to colorName.setBackgroundColor didn't change anything. I tried putting logging statements before the call to setBackgroundColor, and it appears the color integers are being retrieved.
I believe the device I'm using to test is running API 19. So what did I miss?

Edit:
After some more fiddling, I realized it was because the color integers in the DB were generated from R/G/B data only, without the Alpha bits. Calling Color.argb(0xFF, r, g, b) instead of Color.rgb(r, g, b) seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Correct way to get color is: `ContextCompat.getColor(Context context, int id)` - but first debug your code and find out what exactly you are passing to setBackgroundColor by writing in Log.

Comment: Tried that. It's passing the integer values from the database. Also, these colors are retrieved from the database, not stored in resource files, so I don't think ContextCompat will help here.

Comment: If you explicitly set `view.setBackgroundColor(...)` with some predefined color, does that show anything? At least this will decouple if this is the issue with `view.setBackgroundColor(...)` or `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumn...))));`

Comment: Tried it with Color.BLUE, and for some reason, that worked, but the DB-retrieved colors still aren't showing. From the Log, it looks like cursor.getInt is getting the right values. Do they need to be in hex format?

Comment: Here's the code I added to test it.
    int color = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ThreadbasketDB.THREAD_COLOR));
            colorName.setText(Integer.toString(color));
            view.setBackgroundColor(color);